# How can I call these variables in main?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, raspberry-pi2

I have this code that runs and sets the `GPIOS 7,11,13,15` to my `Raspberry Pi 2` `HIGH` or `LOW` so I can address the 16 multiplexer channel accordingly, then reads the analog voltage through and `MCP3002 SPI`, and returns if there was a keypress or a key released, plus which key that was. Here is the code:

```
def findpress(keypressed, keyreleased, key):
    x=0
    while True:
        binary_x="{0:04b}".format(x)
        GPIO.output(7, binary_x[0])
        GPIO.output(11, binary_x[1])
        GPIO.output(13, binary_x[2])
        GPIO.output(15, Binary_x[3])
        channeldata_1 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
        channeldata_2 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
        channeldata_3 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
        channeldata = (channeldata_1+channeldata_2+channeldata_3)/3
        #
        # Voltage = (CHX data * (V-ref [= 3300 mV] * 2 [= 1:2 input divider]) / 1024 [= 10bit resolution]
        #
        voltage = int(round(((channeldata * vref * 2) / resolution),0))+ calibration
        if DEBUG : print("Data (bin)    {0:010b}".format(channeldata))
        if x==15 :      # some problem with this sensor so i had to go and twicked the thresshold
            voltage = voltage - 500
        if voltage<=2500 and keyreleased==True:
            return keypressed=True
            return key=x+1
        if voltage<=2500 and keyreleased==False
            return keypressed=True
            return key=x+1
        if voltage>2500 and keypressed==True:
            x=x+1
            return keyreleased==True
        if x == 15:
            x=0
```

How can I call those variables in `main`?

Comment: *How can I call those variables in main?* << WHICH variables? Also, you may want to show some of your `main` procedure or whatever procedure is calling this one...

Comment: this is my problem ! i have keypressed, keyreleased and key variables that this function is returning. Right ? how can i ask them in main ?

Comment: let's say if keypressed == True do this ?

Comment: Why do you have assignments in the return statements? I think you need to be more clear about what you want returned from your function. The values *or* conveying that events occurred

Comment: conveying that events occurred for keypressed and keyreleased. the value of key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing three arguments *to* this function, presumably *from* the main procedure.

Using tuple unpacking, just return a tuple:

```
print(foo(1, 2, 3)) # should print: 2, 4, 0

# unpacking the tuple like so:
x, y, z = foo(1,2,3)
print x, y, z

def foo(x, y, z):
    x +=1
    y +=2
    z = 0
```

In your code you can simply return some combination like:

```
return keypressed, keyreleased, key
```

Note that multiple return statements like this will not execute as you expect, rather than returning the two values in sequence, it will just stop after the first `return`:

```
        return keypressed=True
        return key=x+1           # This statement will NOT execute
```

Note also that this sort of notation you are currently implementing is going to do an evaluation and return a truthy value:

```
return keypressed=False # returns True if keypressed==False else False
```

If that is your intention, then OK but otherwise you should make your *assignments* prior to the return statements. The workings of your code, and specifically your return statements look like they do not make sense and I'm not really going to troubleshoot those.